# ngOptions storing object inside an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a diet form. It has many days, eating types and products. I will be using the code from [codepen](https://codepen.io/daniss/pen/QKOdwv) to explain the problem. I use ngRepeat to create multiple select forms:

```
<select ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" ng-options="product as product.label for product in products" ng-model="diet[0].products[$index]"></select>
```

What happens is that the diet.products is considered as an object and not as an array of objects:

```
[ { "type": "breakfast", "time": "9:00", "products": { "0": { "label": "Apples", "value": 4, "id": 2 }, "1": { "label": "Apples", "value": 4, "id": 2 } } } ]
```

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="diet[0].type='breakfast'; diet[0].time='9:00'">
        <input type="text" ng-model="diet[0].type">
        <input type="text" ng-model="diet[0].time"> 

        <select ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" ng-options="product as product.label for product in products" ng-model="diet[0].products[$index]">        </select>   
        <p>  {{ selected | json }} </p>
        <p>  {{ diet | json }} </p>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

MyCtrl.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.rows=[{},{}];
     $scope.products = [
       { label: "Apples", value: 4, id: 2 },
       { label: "Oranges", value: 2, id: 1 },
       { label: "Limes", value: 4, id: 4 },
       { label: "Lemons", value: 5, id: 3 }
     ];
      $scope.diet = [];

}]);
```

I cant initialize diet.products as an array because the diet has many days and eating types. Doing this will only work for 0 index array:

```
$scope.diet[0].products = [];
```

Simple  [codepen](https://codepen.io/daniss/pen/QKOdwv) example.

**EDIT:** The full diet creation form looks like this: You enter in the days for your diet, for example 10 and you have 10 tabs available. Each tab means a single day and contains all these 6 eating types (Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, etc.). Next you have 6 eating type tables like [this one](http://oi63.tinypic.com/ohs6y8.jpg) where you add in products by typing it into the input field and specifying the quantity. Each day and each eating type might have unique products.

**EDIT2:** I wanted to make it so that you could create the diet in one go. This isnt intended to be a single page aplication. I use laravel on backend.

**EDIT3:**
**Diet js** desired structure

```
[
    {
        "day":1,
        "eating_types":[ 
           {"type":"Breakfast","time":"8:00", "products":[]},
           {"type":"Lunch","time":"12:00", "products":[]}
        ]
    },
    {
        "day":2,
        "eating_types":[ 
           {"type":"Breakfast","time":"8:00", "products":[]},
           {"type":"Lunch","time":"12:00", "products":[]}
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: @charlietfl it appears to be multiple `<select>` elements with the same set of options

Comment: http://oi63.tinypic.com/ohs6y8.jpg Original project has typeheads just wanted to make it more simple

Comment: Quick note; you don't need the *select as* syntax. Just use `product.label for product in products track by product.id`

Comment: What's the point of `diet[0]`? Why is `diet` an array? What **exactly** do you want the end result to look like?

Comment: @Phil seems to make more sense it would be a single multiple select . Never seen a UI with multiple select stacked back to back with same options like that have you?

Comment: @charlietfl well, not until now ;)

Comment: @Phil The diet has multiple days that have multiple eating types and multiple products. for example Day 1 has breakfast with 2 products apple and banana

Comment: @Danis then your example code is not really a good representation of what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So presumably you've got something where the user enters the number of days / diets / whatever. When you handle that input, why not just initialise your `diet` array completely

```js
let numberOfDays = 10; // for example, this would come from the user

let diet = Array.apply(null, {length: numberOfDays}).map((tmp, n) => ({
  day: n + 1,
  eating_types: [
    {type: "Breakfast", time: "8:00", products: []},
    {type: "Lunch", time: "12:00", products: []}
  ]
}));

console.log(diet);
```

Comment: It was just an example. I have a Diet form where you can add in different products for Breakfast Lunch and other eating types. What do you mean by more dynamic ? So doing something like diet[0].products = [] would only for for breakfast for example

Comment: @Danis more dynamic meaning *"not a static `0`"*. I still don't know what you're trying to achieve with the `diet` array because you haven't explained it properly or with a decent example. My answer does however solve your initial problem of `products` being an object instead of an array

Comment: could you demonstrate it ? Because I thought diets[].products = [] would work for all the array elements

Comment: No, I could not because I still have no idea why `diet` is an array. It's your project, you should explain it (with code). Also, `diets[].products` is an invalid expression

Comment: I edited the post explaining it. I hope it will be more clear.

Comment: @Danis now I really don't understand the problem. You already appear to be initialising the `Products` property (now with a capital "P" and part of the `eating_types` array) as an array. Your initial question does not appear to reflect anything you're actually wanting to do

Comment: Thats supposed to be an example. I added 2 days and 2 eating types to show why would Diet be an array. Its not the actual code but just the desired json structure since I have an empty Diet array initialized just like in the example.

Comment: @Danis I've overhauled my answer